# how to move camera in order to provide rotation and scaling of a 3d object in android?

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es

i have created a cube. now i want to perform rotation, zooming and panning functions by moving camera. like moving camera far will zoom out and near will zoom in.
please help as i am new in android and openGL-es.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as camera in OpenGL. There are only two transformation matrices: model-view and projection. First you have to setup your projection matrix. You can do that using glFrustum or manually. Read this [article](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html) about projections.

Then in order to fake the camera behavior you need to use inverse transformation matrix. It means that if you want to move your camera for (0,0,-5) you need to move the whole world for (0,0,5). The same is with rotation and scaling.

You should read the OpenGL Red Book, it is all described there.